# Convert a column of a data frame into numeric only when it makes sense

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric, coercion

```
data0 = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c("a","b","c","d"),c=c("1","2","3","4"))
data0[,2] = as.character(data0[,2])
data0[,3] = as.character(data0[,3])

class(data0[,2])
class(data0[,3])
data0[,2] = as.numeric(data0[,2])
data0[,3] = as.numeric(data0[,3])

class(data0[,2])
class(data0[,3])
data0[,2]
data0[,3]
```

In the data frame `data0`, column `b` is really character but column `c` is actually numeric.
I would like to convert a character column into a numeric column 'only when' it makes sense.
If I run the above code, column `c` is converted to numeric which I intented, but column `b` is converted to `NA` which I do not want.
How can I convert 'actually numeric' columns to numeric while keeping the others untouched?

Comment: Try with `type.convert` ie. `data0[] <- lapply(data0, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))`

Comment: @akrun It's a great solution. One problem is that "POSIXct" type is also converted to character, but I want to keep it as it is.

Comment: Yes, for that you need `inherits`

Comment: @akrun I read the help document of the function 'inherit' but cannot figure out what I should do. Could you explain in detail?

Answer (score 3):

The `all.is.numeric` function from the `HMisc` package - combined with `dplyr`-style mutating - comes to mind here:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)    

data0 %>%
  mutate_if(all.is.numeric, as.numeric)
```

`all.is.numeric` checks whether all elements in a character vector are actually numeric, and the `mutate_if` bit then converts all columns for which this is true to numeric.

Comment: What is the difference between  mutate_if(all.is.numeric(data0), as.numeric(data0)) and your command?

Comment: My code uses the pipe operator `%/%` to access the df, yours doesn't (and throws a bug in my case). An alternative without the piple would be `mutate_if(data0, all.is.numeric, as.numeric)`. Also, for both alternatives, don't forget to save the df in a (new or existing) object, a la `data1 <- data0 %>%
  mutate_if(all.is.numeric, as.numeric)`